# Wrong constructor called in custom vector class

Tags: c++, vector, constructor

I'm fairly new to C++ and as a learning exercise I'm creating my own simple vector class.

It seems to work well, except when I create a Vec object trying to use the
 Vec(size_type n, const T& val = T()) constructor, it instead wants to use the templated constructor that is supposed to take two iterators/pointers, and gives me errors.

I believe that I understand why this is happening, but I can't think of a way to make it less ambiguous without changing the way the class is used.  I want to keep the use the same as with a std::vector.

How can I get the proper constructor called?  How does the std::vector avoid this problem?

**Vec.h**

```
//#includes: <algorithm> <cstddef> <memory>

template <class T> class Vec
{
public:
//typedefs for iterator, size_type....
//just used T* for iterator

    Vec() { create(); }
    Vec(const Vec& v) { create(v.begin(), v.end()); }
    explicit Vec(size_type n, const T& val = T()) { create(n, val); }

    template <class InputIt>
    Vec(InputIt first, InputIt last) { create(first, last); }

    ~Vec() { uncreate(); }

    T& operator[](size_type i) { return data[i]; }
    const T& operator[](size_type i) const { return data[i]; }
    Vec& operator=(const Vec&);

    //functions such as begin(), size(), etc...

private:
    iterator data;
    iterator avail;
    iterator limit;

    std::allocator<T> alloc;
    void create();
    void create(size_type, const T&);

    template <class InputIt>
    void create(InputIt first, InputIt last)
    {
        data = alloc.allocate(last - first);
        limit = avail = std::uninitialized_copy(first, last, data);
    }

    void uncreate();
    void grow();
    void unchecked_append(const T&);
};

template <class T>
Vec<T>& Vec<T>::operator=(const Vec& rhs)
{
    if (&rhs != this)
    {
        uncreate();
        create(rhs.begin(), rhs.end());
    }
    return *this;
}

template <class T> void Vec<T>::create()
{
    data = avail = limit = 0;
}

template <class T> void Vec<T>::create(size_type n, const T& val)
{
    data = alloc.allocate(n);
    limit = avail = data + n;
    std::uninitialized_fill(data, limit, val);
}

template <class T>
void Vec<T>::create(const_iterator i, const_iterator j)
{
    data = alloc.allocate(j - i);
    limit = avail = std::uninitialized_copy(i, j, data);
}

template <class T> void Vec<T>::uncreate()
{
    if (data)
    {
        iterator it = avail;
        while (it != data)
            alloc.destroy(--it);
        alloc.deallocate(data, limit - data);
    }
    data = limit = avail = 0;
}

//left out what I didn't think was relevant
```

It seems to work fine except the case I mentioned above.

**main.cpp**

```
#include "Vec.h"

main()
{
    Vec<int> v1(10, 100);
}
```

I get errors:

```
||=== Build: Debug in Vec Class (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
c:\program files\codeblocks\mingw\bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.7.1\include\c++\bits\stl_uninitialized.h||In instantiation of '_ForwardIterator std::uninitialized_copy(_InputIterator, _InputIterator, _ForwardIterator) [with _InputIterator = int; _ForwardIterator = int*]':|
F:\CBProjects\Accelerated C++\Programming with Classes\Vec Class\Vec.h|58|required from 'void Vec::create(InputIt, InputIt) [with InputIt = int; T = int]'|
F:\CBProjects\Accelerated C++\Programming with Classes\Vec Class\Vec.h|24|required from 'Vec::Vec(InputIt, InputIt) [with InputIt = int; T = int]'|
F:\CBProjects\Accelerated C++\Programming with Classes\Vec Class\main.cpp|9|required from here|
c:\program files\codeblocks\mingw\bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.7.1\include\c++\bits\stl_uninitialized.h|113|error: no type named 'value_type' in 'struct std::iterator_traits'|
||=== Build failed: 1 error(s), 4 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|
```

This is my first time asking a question on here.  I hope I asked properly and provided enough information.  Please let me know if I made a mistake in this process, and thank you for any help you can provide.

### **EDIT:**

For anyone wondering what I ended up doing.  I changed the templated constructor so that it won't be invoked with arithmetic arguments(since it's only meant for iterators/pointers).

```
template <class InputIt>
Vec(InputIt first, InputIt last,
    typename std::enable_if<!std::is_arithmetic<InputIt>::value>::type* = 0) {create(first, last); }
```

It seems to work fine, but I'm actually not very familiar with enable_if, so if anyone knows any dangers to this approach, please let me know.

Comment: There'a missing `)` in `Vec(const Vec& v) { create(v.begin(), v.end(); }`.

Comment: @R Sahu: That was just a typo on the post, not in the real program.  Thanks for pointing it out though.

Comment: A work-around `Vec<int> v1(Vec<int>::size_type(10), 100);`

Comment: @pmr Why doesn't it work?

Comment: @NeilKirk Thanks, that does work.  A bit unwieldy, but solves the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The templated constructor is chosen since it is a better match for the arguments.

Looking at the documentation of the [vector constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector) you will see a note that this constructor only participates in overload resolution if the arguments satisfy the requirements of `InputIterator`. This is usually achieved by disabling an overload using [SFINAE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitution_failure_is_not_an_error). The following is how libcpp achieves that. I tried to cut away some unnecessary bits and adjusted the naming conventions to make for better readability.

A usual definition of this constructor in an actual implementation would look like this:

```
template <class InputIterator>
vector(InputIterator first, InputIterator last,
       typename enable_if<is_input_iterator  <InputIterator>::value>::type* = 0);
template <class InputIterator>
vector(InputIterator first, InputIterator last, const allocator_type& a,
       typename enable_if<is_input_iterator  <InputIterator>::value>::type* = 0);
```

I removed the unnecessary parts that further differentiates between `InputIterator` and `ForwardIterator`. The important part for [SFINAE is the enable_if](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if) and its arguments.

Here are the necessary definitions of `is_input_iterator`:

```
template <class Tp, class Up,
          bool = has_iterator_category<iterator_traits<Tp> >::value>
struct has_iterator_category_convertible_to
    // either integral_constant<bool, false> or integral_constant<bool, true>
  : public integral_constant<
      bool, 
      is_convertible<typename iterator_traits<Tp>::iterator_category, Up>::value
    >
{};

// specialization for has_iterator_category<iterator_traits<Tp> >::value == false
template <class Tp, class Up>
struct has_iterator_category_convertible_to<Tp, Up, false> : public false_type {};

template <class Tp>
struct is_input_iterator 
  : public has_iterator_category_convertible_to<Tp, input_iterator_tag> {};
```

The essence of it is that it checks if a given type has an `iterator_category` tag that can be converted to `input_iterator_tag`.

`has_iterator_category` is even more obscure:

```
template <class Tp>
struct has_iterator_category
{
private:
    struct two {char lx; char lxx;};
    template <class Up> static two test(...);
    template <class Up> static char test(typename Up::iterator_category* = 0);
public:
    static const bool value = sizeof(test<Tp>(0)) == 1;
};
```

It is used to check if a given type has a member called `iterator_category` or not. If the answer is `no` `has_iterator_category_convertible_to` will simply default to `false_type`. If this wouldn't be done a non-exisiting name would be accessed and a hard compiler error would be triggered, which is not what you want to do in SFINAE.

Comment: But what if a raw pointer is passed in.  It wouldn't have tag.  Or is that accounted for in _is_input_iterator?

Comment: @liquidhand `iterator_traits` is required to be specialized for raw pointers.

Comment: I realize now why most examples of simple vector classes left out that constructor.  It's a bit beyond the scope of most beginner lessons.  Thanks for helping me understand.

Comment: @liquidhand Yes, it involves two of the more advanced template techniques. But it is very effective at showing how complicated templates actually can be.

Comment: I came up with a simpler work around using enable_if and !is_arithmetic.  Since as far as I can tell it's just int's that create any constructor confusion.  It might not be ideal, but it seems to be working.